# Repeating Creating Object until it gets executed

Tags: vba, com

I would like to repeat Creating Object until it gets created (opened).

In my case the problem looks like this. Application is opened via COM and access is controlled via licensing service. While all licenses are in use, you eventually will get an error as shown in attached image. But when free license will appear, you will be able to launch the application.

```
Dim ApplicationName As Object
Set ApplicationName = CreateObject("AppNameToLaunchViaCOM")
```

Is there any way to do it? And maybe inform the user how many times it failed to open etc.

[Server Execution Failed window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6LCq.png)

Comment: What about a loop `While ApplicationName Is Nothing` and some reasonable delay between each attempt with `Application.Wait`

Comment: @Toddleson Thanks, it seems to work fine for me. One attempt takes 10 minutes to make the licensing service decline your request so no need to wait.

While ApplicationName Is Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set ApplicationName = CreateObject("AppNameToLaunchViaCOM")
If ApplicationName Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print "Error running ApplicationName. Trying Again..."
    NoOfConnectionAttempts = NoOfConnectionAttempts + 1
    Application.StatusBar = "Failed to load ApplicationName. Trying again... Attempt: " & NoOfConnectionAttempts
End If
On Error GoTo 0
Wend

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you! Go ahead and submit an answer to your own question, so that others who have this problem in the future can benefit from this knowledge. Although I'm not sure about the reputation required for that action.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following approach

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" _
    (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)

Function getObj() As Object
    On Error GoTo EH
    
    Dim ApplicationName As Object
    Set ApplicationName = CreateObject("AppNameToLaunchViaCOM")
    
    Set getObj = ApplicationName
    
    Exit Function
    
EH:
    
End Function

Sub TryOut()
    Const MAX = 10
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim myObj As Object

    Do
    
        Set myObj = getObj
        If Not myObj Is Nothing Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        
        ' Code to wait
        Sleep 1000
        
        ' exit loop in case more than max tries
        i = i + 1
    Loop Until i > MAX
    
    If myObj Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "No license"
        ' furher code
    Else
        Debug.Print "Tries", i
        ' furher code
    End If

End Sub
```